# deciphering a phrase that sounds like "enakatasu"

Tags: listening

I'm having trouble deciphering the phrase marked with ??? in the following sentence:

It sounds like enakatasu

In the transcript, this phrase is written as 「へなく+」
Is this correct? If so, how do you translate this phrase?

[video starting @ 1:04](https://youtu.be/-Yli8mH-LOE?t=1m4s)

私今？？？ていうサークルに入っているんですけどそこでは困っている人を助けたり私がやっているような日本を教えたりっていう活動をしています。

Comment: http://www.voluntary.jp/weblog/RedirectServlet?npoURL=enactus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from l'électeur above has the answer. In the video, the presenter is talking about the name of a global non-profit student group she is in, Enactus (エナクタス in Japanese). See https://enactus.org for more info.